# Docker static ip connection timeout from outside

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, ipv4

I am trying to assign my APP with a static IP. I think I have assigned the IP, but I cannot reach the IP from outside either curl or the browser.

docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  client:
    container_name: client
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app/
      - /app/node_modules
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10
    hostname: client
    command: npm run dev
networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "172.16.238.0/24"
```

Terminal message when I run it:

```
client    | > frontend@0.0.0 dev
client    | > vite
client    | 
client    | 
client    |   VITE v3.2.2  ready in 710 ms
client    | 
client    |   ➜  Local:   http://localhost:3000/
client    |   ➜  Network: http://172.16.238.10:3000/
```

I can reach `http://localhost:3000/` on the browser just fine. But whenever I try to reach `http://172.16.238.10:3000/`, I get a timeout. Something this on the browser:

```
This site can’t be reached
172.16.238.10 took too long to respond.
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I can curl to the IP I assigned inside the docker container, but I cannot do it from outside. Is it possible to expose the IP to the outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manage to assign another IP address (172.16.238.10) to the host, the container can continue having a dynamic IP address. You can map the port 3000 only to the IP address 172.16.238.10.

Then you can connect to 172.16.238.10:3000 as so:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  client:
    container_name: client
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - 172.16.238.10:3000:3000
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app/
      - /app/node_modules
    networks:
      - app_net
    hostname: client
    command: npm run dev
networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look at using a [macvlan network](https://docs.docker.com/network/macvlan/) instead of bridged.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you can't access the container-private IP addresses at all.  It happens to be possible on native Linux, not using Docker Desktop or another VM-based setup, and only if you're on the same machine as the container, but given all of these constraints it's usually better to not try it.

The standard way to access a container from outside is to declare `ports:` for it, and to use the host's DNS name or IP address and the published port number.  Don't declare any IP-related setup in your Compose file at all.

Assuming your Dockerfile is correctly constructed, you should be able to reduce that Compose file to just

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  client:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

and calling `http://host.example.com:3000/` using your host's DNS name, or `http://localhost:3000` if you're on the same host, will forward to port 3000 in the container.  None of the other Compose options are necessary.